# basic probability problems on sample space, distribution function, etc.

Tags: probability

Problem 2 (page 33 of text) Assume that every patient with a particular type of disease has the probability 0.1 of being cured within a week, if the patient is given no treatment for the disease. Ten patients with that type of disease are given a new type of drug. After one week 9 out of 10 patients are cured.

(a) What is the probability that at least 9 patients are cured if the drug is assumed to have no curative effects?

(b) In your opinion, would you consider this drug beneficial?

(c) What sample space did you use in this analysis?

(d) What probability function did you define on the sample space?

(e) What is the name of the probability distribution of your random variable?

my question is..

what is the complement of the event "being cured within a week w/o treatment"?

If you answer all the questions above, really appreciated.

I'm stuck in this problem for a week.

plz help me getting out of this.!!

Comment: What did you do to solve this during one week?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the events

$$C=\text{patient cured within 1 week}$$

$$C'= \text{patient }not \text{ cured within 1 week}$$

$$D=\text{patient given drug}$$

$$D'= \text{patient }not \text{ given drug}$$

You are given

$$P(C|D')=0.1$$

$$C|D =0.9$$

And if the drug has no effect then $P(C|D)=P(C|D')$

Comment: thumbs up! thanks